# Show language not regular

Tags: regular-languages

How can I show that $\{a^ib^jc^k|i=0 \lor j=k\}$ is not regular?

I tried applying the pumping lemma but it does seem to have a pumping length of 1?

Alternatively there is the Myhill–Nerode theorem. 
Are $\{a^ib^j|i=0 \lor j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ infinite many equivalence classes?

Comment: it involves the language a^nb^n which is not regular and FM can't count unlimited number.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the intersection of your language with $ab^*c^*$.

Comment: Then we would get the nonregular language $b^nc^n$ but which theorem can I use on the intersection?

Comment: Closure under intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Myhill-Nerode theorem: For every j, j' the strings $ab^j$ and $ab^{j'}$, $j ≠ j'$, can be distinguished - because one can be followed by $c^j$ and the other can't.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with **Pumping Theory** (P.T.) of Regular Languages, that is to assume the language is regular and **pick ${n}$ in P.T. as** ${n=j=k}$. Then follow the three rules in P.T. for a **contradiction**.